# Find new template Email Resetting Password FOS Fos User Bundle

Tags: symfony, email, fosuserbundle, reset

I'm trying to reformat the whole email of resetting password from fos user bundle.

The email file it's called and located in Resources/views/Resetting/email.txt.twig and I would like to reformat it to Resources/views/Resetting/email.html.twig. I need the file being in the html format because I need to add more sections to the email.

I saw there is a mention of this tempalte inside Resources/config/mailer.xml so I tried to modify it but can't success.

Could anyone explain me how to be able to use Resources/views/Resetting/email.html.twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at  https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/emails.html#sending-html-mails

```
fos_user:
    # ...
service:
    mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
resetting:
    email:
        template:   '@AppBundle/Resetting/email.html.twig'
```

you may need to modify the template path `'@AppBundle/Resetting/email.html.twig'`

Comment: Thank u mate. By the way, do youn know how to add html content to the email? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50818949/changing-content-template-fosuserbundle